# Typescript - exclude reserved word from string

Tags: typescript

I wish to define an interface that does not allow to assign 'options' string on configNames field, but couldn't figure out how to make it work:

```
// First try
interface Options<T = string> {
    configNames: T extends 'options' ? never: string;
}

// No validation because 'options' is subset of string, thus the type is always false, thus configName type is string
const options: Options = {
    configNames: 'options'
}

// Second try
interface Options<T> {
    configNames: T extends 'options' ? never: string;
}

// typescript error: Generic type 'Options<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
const options: Options = {
    configNames: 'options'
}
```

Would there be any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: There is no specific type that does this; TS doesn't have negated types, so there's no way to say "`string & not "options"`".  You can use your generic type with a helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nnexew) to get similar behavior, where instead of `const o: Options = {...}` you write `const o = options({...})`.  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am trying to make a pull request for type definition file (.d.ts) in an existing library from DefinitelyTyped repo and `interface Options` is predefined as an object. The suggestion altering type from object to function won't be accepted by the maintainer  did I understand your suggestion correctly?

Comment: I think you may have understood correctly... but as there is no specific type in TypeScript that works the way you need, I'm afraid the answer is therefore "this is not currently possible".  Do you want me to write up an answer explaining this?  Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: This can't currently be accomplished using inference with an object literal — or by relying on a default generic type parameter that extends `string` — but if you are willing to provide the appropriate generic string literal then you can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wva7km). Does that satisfy your criteria? If so, I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz yes! I'd appreciate if you write up the answer so this post can be useful for the future.

Comment: @jsejcksn great type definition for `StringLiteralExcept` and good to know about new `satisfies` operator. I' m looking for ways to define types rather than validating type later on. As you wrote, maybe there is no such a way! But thanks for sharing the reference, I even didn't know there is a comment macro on typescript playground!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific type in TypeScript corresponding to "all `string`s except for `"options"`".  That would require something like *negated types* as suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#4196](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196) (and even as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) which was never merged).  If TypeScript had negated types you could presumably write something like `string & not "options"`.  But it doesn't, so you can't.  If using a specific `Options` type is a requirement, then what you want is currently impossible.

---

So you're left with workarounds.  There are no specific types, but you could make `Options<T>` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type (as shown in your first try) and then use it as a *constraint* on a candidate type.  And you could write a helper function to infer the generic type argument `T` for you.  So while there's no way to write `const o: Options = {...}` and have it behave as desired, you *could* write `const o = options({...})` and get a similar effect (and  those aren't really very different if you squint at them).

The idea is to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to filter out `"options"` from any string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in `T`.  You could use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to do this:

```
interface Options<T extends string> {
  configNames: Exclude<T, "options">
}
```

That's similar to your version.  Also, if you want to prohibit `string` itself (so that `{configNames: someRandomString}` is rejected, since it could be `"options"`), you could augment the definition to do that also:

```
interface Options<T extends string> {
  configNames: string extends T ? never : Exclude<T, "options">
}
```

It's up to you whether you care about false positives or false negatives more.  Anyway, the helper function would look like

```
const options = <T extends string>(o: Options<T>) => o;
```

And now you can test it out:

```
const bad = options({
  configNames: 'options' // error!
});

const good = options({
  configNames: 'somethingElse' // okay
});
// const good: Options<"somethingElse">

function foo(someRandomString: string) {
  const maybe = options({
    configNames: someRandomString // maybe error depending on needs
  })
}
```

Looks good.  You get the validation you care about.  It's somewhat different from your desired approach, but it has the benefit of being possible to implement.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/PQKgsAUMwAQHIHkAqMBqBBAMgSQCIyQE0AFAUQGUBhAJW2KQBoZcF5kDrCCAJbcgLkgBLAHYAXAKYAnAGYBDAMYSYCAA5ihAexEBnGAG9IMGAu0yhAczhyAthJ38YOsVNEWYAMhgjNYmACJNdS1df0gAX0gQYEhhcWl5JRVg7R0AHhQJAA9JEQATPWdXEQsAPgMjEzNLazsHJxc3GGzcgoIYAH5vCQA3aRhHUiyFABsAVzyJDKZAlNDSiMhTXT8gjVSYAF4YDOaciXzCxpLSgApNRzV13QzSgEot8s0AbliIZecYACM5PK2YNYhHSnQwQYzLcxWWz2RwAckBqVhMGgzSkUk0UgAhBE7q8IEtUn4LJpNH9tgjdCDKhCatD6rCdJo7GIABZuUgjHQSJEozQAazkAE8cXiUR8iSS8pc5ul-IzmWyShyuf4FviIDIxiIFNcYDISad5RJqHJ8kzyMcLI4im4HqDwYSYDYhV9lOSZVSwcYqiJIbUYU4mcbTXlzZbkbBpOisZVwncIkA)